# EditTexts with links both clickable and editable

Tags: android, android-edittext, linkmovementmethod

I am working with EditText which take WebUrl in input.For that I am using `LinkMovementMethod` Make links in the EditText clickable.

Problem is that :

> If the last part of the text is a link, clicking anywhere causes the
>   link to be opened.

I want when I am clicking on **click here to edit** area edittext, It will be editable?

[image]

Comment: You can try with long press.

Comment: What is different about your situation from http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/14/making-edittexts-with-links-both-clickable-and-editable/ , which says this feature already works the way you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel Lew wrote the blog post about it several days ago. He suggests next solution:

```
// Make links in the EditText clickable
editText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

// Setup my Spannable with clickable URLs
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString("http://blog.danlew.net");  
Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

// The fix: Append a zero-width space to the Spannable
CharSequence text = TextUtils.concat(spannable, "\u200B");

// Use it!
editText.setText(text);
```

You can find post here: [Making EditTexts with links both clickable and editable](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/14/making-edittexts-with-links-both-clickable-and-editable/)

Answer (score 0):

check the following code.

```
EditText inputText;
//Edittext is clickable at right side.
inputText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (event.getRawX() >= (inputText.getRight() - inputText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                   //write your logic
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```